# Check if JSON contains value pair from another JSON

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to compare 2 JSONs whether there are two values in a combination or not.

For e.g.

**wechselwirkungen**

```
[{"1": 1234, "2": 5678}, {"1": 2222, "2": 1111}, {"1": 2222, "2": 5678}]
```

**medArray**

```
[{"Code": 1234}, {"Code": 5678}, {"Code": 2222}]
```

**Expected Output**: In this example it should return the arrays with index 0 and 2 of 'wechselwirkungen'

```
[{"1": 1234, "2": 5678}, {"1": 2222, "2": 5678}]
```

I've tried with two nested loops but It doesn't work

```
function findPairs(medArray) {

  for(var i=0;i<wechselwirkungen.length;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<medArray.length;j++){
     console.log("test", wechselwirkungen[i][1].includes(medArray[j].Code))
      if(wechselwirkungen[i][1].includes(medArray[j].Code) && wechselwirkungen[i][2].includes(medArray[j].Code)){
      console.log('test wechselwirkungen: ' + wechselwirkungen[i] + ' medArray:' + medArray[j]);
    }
   }
  }

}
```

Thank you for your hints

Comment: *Why* is that the expected result, such that I could tell what the expected result should be for any pair of lists?

Comment: Because 'wechselwirkungen' contains a pair of values which are included in medArray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check **all** properties and filter the array.

```js
const
    wechselwirkungen = [{ 1: 1234, 2: 5678 }, { 1: 2222, 2: 1111 }, { 1: 2222, 2: 5678 }],
    medArray = [{ Code: 1234 }, { Code: 5678 }, { Code: 2222 }],
    codes = medArray.map(({ Code }) => Code),
    result = wechselwirkungen.filter(o => Object
        .values(o)
        .every(v => codes.includes(v))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```